# A <div></div> is supposed to be rectangle or square, can we use html5 or any other method of web technology to make it appear like a rhombus?

Tags: html

A `<div></div>` is supposed to be rectangle or square, can we use html5 or any other method of web technology to make it appear like a rhombus?

I know html5 can create a tilted line to write text or even rotate them.

Answer (score 6):

you are looking for something like this--with your css

```
#rhombusDiv { 
 width: 150px; 
 height: 100px;
 -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
 -moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
 -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  background: blue;
 }
```

see this fiddle for example - 
http://jsfiddle.net/xtXRQ/

Answer (score 1):

Div is neither a square, nor a rectangle. It just defines a division or a section in an HTML document. You could make it like rectangle or square by putting css on it.

You can use HTML5 Canvas to draw a rhombus

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_canvas.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**  You could use RaphaelJS for this purpose.

See this jsfiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NQtU5/

[RaphaelJS](http://www.raphaeljs.com) uses VML / SVG, depending on which one is available - which more or less guarantees cross-browser compatibility.  This method works in IE and FF/Safari/Chrome and gives you some interface flexibility.

First, create an absolutely positioned DIV named r_paper:

```
<div id="r_paper"></div>
```

Link to the RaphaelJS library, and then, in JavaScript, do this:

```
var paper = Raphael( "r_paper" );
paper.path(
    "m10,140 l125,-100 l125,100 l-125,100 l-125,-100"
).attr({
    'stroke-width': 5, fill: 'crimson'
});
```

[image]

Note that the 'paper' DIV element (think of it as canvas) is styled as such:

```
#r_paper { 
    position: absolute;
    width:270px; height:270px;
    left: 100px; top:100px
}
```